# Excel VBA Indicator Function for Macro

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

Suppose I have the following Data

```
Name   Date       Notional

Alice 10/1/2006&  1000  

Bob   12/5/2011  5000 

Dawn    1/1/2010   400

Alice   5/6/2009   500

Alice   7/13/2012   1500

Dawn    4/5/2012    100
```

I want to add two more columns, Total and Percentage. Where Total sums Notional per person and Percentage looks at a given Notional as a percentage of Total.

So Alice has three trades on three dates with three notionals of 1000, 500, and 1500. Her Total would be 3000 and her three percentages would be 33%, 16.6% and 50%

So my final result would be:

```
Name    Date       Notional    Total    Percentage

Alice   10/1/2006  1000        3000       33%

Bob     12/5/2011  5000        5000       100% 

Dawn    1/1/2010   400         500        80%        

Alice   5/6/2009   500         3000       16.67% 

Alice   7/13/2012   1500       3000       50%  

Dawn    4/5/2012    100        500        20%
```

I am hoping to write a Macro that adds an Sums the Notional for everyone provided the Name matches.

So my cell D2 will be C2 * Indicator(A2,A2) + C3 * Indicator(A3,A2) + C4*Indicator(A4,A2) + C5*Indicator(A5,A2) + C6*Indicator(A6=A2) + C7*Indicator(A7=A2)

Where Indicator(Ak,A2) is an indicator function which takes the value 1 when Range("Ak").Value=Range("A2").Value and zero otherwise.

Is there such a function? I suppose I can create one myself.

```
Public Function Indicator(c1 As Range, c2 As Range)
       Dim out As Integer
       If Range(c1).Value = Range(c2).Value Then
          out = 1
          Else: out = 0
          End If


End Function
```

I am trying to get this to run inside a bigger code. But right now I am getting a lot of errors. I will update if I can get it to run.

Comment: Can you use a Pivot Table? I think that it's the easist way to do this.

Comment: You can't use formulas? `SUMIF()` would work just fine here.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks. I am using SUMIF now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built a Pivot Table with:

Lines:  Name | Date

Values: Notional [SUM] | Notional [% of parent row total]